# How to call PL/SQL (Procedure present in package Not PL/SQL statement) in nodejs oracledb?

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

My procedures are present in oracle packages. I want to call procedure instead of writing PL/SQL statement in node file itself. e.g.
I want to replace **'select * from X_CS_CONTRACT'** with package.procedurename
**like C#**
 **rightsGranted = dbClient.ExecuteDataTable(PKGCommonConstants.GetRightsGranted, dbCmdParam);**

`

```
app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    const plsqlpackageProcedure = 'select * from X_CS_CONTRACT'
    let bindVars = {
      O_CUR_RGTSGRAN_TYP: {type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT}
    }
    oracledb.getConnection(config)
            .then(conn => conn.execute(plsqlpackageProcedure, [], bindVars))
            .then(queryResult => {console.log(queryResult); res.send(JSON.stringify(queryResult))})
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
  });

  app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 3000');
  });
```

`

Comment: Have you seend these examples for PL/SQL? Function: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlfunc.js and Procedure: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlproc.js. Using a package only requires that you prefix the function or procedure name with the package name.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me. I have replaced with
const plsqlpackageProcedure = 'BEGIN  X_PKG_CS_MASTER_DATA.X_PRC_CS_RIGHTSGRANT(:O_CUR_RGTSGRAN_TYP); END;'

Comment: Don't forget to release connections.  It's a good habit.